# Методы жизненного цикла React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Какие на данный момент можно использовать методы жизненного цикла в React? В интернете только устаревшая информация а в оф. документации расписано много обновлений в которых уже всё потерялось и чётко не расписано какие устарели а какие нет.

Comment: Классы, а вместе с ними - `LifeCycle`, устарели. React-сообщество плавно переходит на хуки. Используйте их

Answer (score 1):

Хук useEffect() включает необходимые методы